# How to hide terms from entity reference field on node form

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I've been searching quite a bit on this already and was not able to find a solution.
installation is d10
So on my node I have an entity reference field which is showing Taxonomy terms. Two of those taxonomy terms should always be hidden on the node form. But they should exist as taxonomy terms, so removing them from the taxonomy is not an option.
I tried using hook_form_alter() and unsetting the keys, but that didn't work.

Anyone has experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm wondering if you could use a Views entity reference with a filter to get what you want, then choose that View in the Term entity reference field settings

Comment: @WebAssistant That would be a solution, I will try this.

Comment: @WebAssistant Hey I just tested that, and that works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@WebAssistant 's answer:

create an Entity Reference View and use a filter to remove the unwanted terms.
In the settings of the reference field on the node choose: Views: filter by an entity reference view. Choose the view you created and voila.